# Add location and timezone to chat profile

Tags: feature-request, chat, profile-page

With chat, the location and timezone of each person is now useful since we can infer when a user might be online through his/her location. Since location information is already collected for the parent profile, it certainly make sense to display this information on the chat profile as well.

Here's a bunch of mockups I've created:

[image]

[image]

Timezone information can be collected using JavaScript, and the user will have a choice over whether these information will be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, at one point we *did* display the location, but general consensus is that it was irrelevant for chat; or at least, so rarely relevant that it doesn't matter. Re when you are likely to be around... the *activity graph* tells you that...

[image]